# Galaxy S6 Screen Height Points

Tags: screen

What is the screen height of the galaxy s6 in points?   For example the iphone 6 plus is 414 x 736 points. How can i get that for the galaxy s6, i've searched quite a bit for it and still haven't found anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me, what does this have to do with Android? It has to with the hardware of a specific device, which we don't address here. You could try looking for a formula to convert pixels to points, or a use photo editor which can do it(Photoshop comes to mind)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, screen size in points depends on screen scaling.

Size for iPhone 6 Plus with default @3x scaling is: `414 x 736` points and `1242 x 2208` pixels - `401 ppi.`

Size for Galaxy S6 with same @3x scaling is: `480 x 853` points and `1440 x 2560` pixels - `577 ppi.`